# How to use db stores?

Tags: openiddict

New to openiddict and just wondering if there are samples of how to configure a db client store along with tables required/migrations that can be run.  The samples all seem to show in memory client db.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you use Entity Framework Core, there's nothing OpenIddict-specific in this process, except the `options.UseOpenIddict()` call needed to register the OpenIddict entities, as mentioned in the getting started docs: https://documentation.openiddict.com/guide/getting-started.html

For a more complete sample, see https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-samples/tree/dev/samples/Velusia/Velusia.Server.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I figured out IO had to call builder.UseOpenIddict() on building db context.